# Convexity of log-determinant

Tags: convex-analysis

I'm having a difficult time determining if the following function is convex

$$f(X) = \log {\rm det}(X^T A X)$$

where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times u}$ with $u < r$ and $X'X = I$. I've worked on find the second derivative with respect to $X$, but am not very confident in my solution. Any suggests on steps to proceed would be appreciated.

EDIT: Because the domain of $X$ is nonconvex, the function cannot be convex, as pointed out by @RobertIsrael.

Comment: Use $\det(XY) = \det X \det Y$, $\det X^T = \det X$ and $\det X > 0$ if $X$ is positive definite to reduce the problem to $g(\alpha) = \log \alpha$ where $\alpha \in R^{+}$.

Comment: Is this true for all $X$ and $Y$? My impression was that this only held for square $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: No only square.  Need to think again.

Comment: If its any help, $\frac{\partial}{\partial X} \log{\rm det}(X^TAX) = 2(X^TAX)^{-1}AX$. I was stuck on taking the second derivative.

Comment: I was thinking of Jacobi's formula.

Comment: I assume you've used $\log \det(X) = \text{tr} \log (X)$ in coming up with the first derivative and that hasn't helped?

Comment: No I didn't. For d1, use $\frac{\partial \log {\rm \det}(X^TAX)}{\partial (X^TAX)} \frac{\partial X^TAX }{\partial X}$. And I am not sure that what you've written makes sense; how are you defining $\log(X)$? Elementwise?

Comment: $X^T X = I$?  The set of such $X$ is not convex, so how can you even ask if $f(X)$ is convex?

Comment: log(X) is the [logarithm of a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix).

Comment: @RoberIsreal Good point.

Comment: One way to examine Robert's point is to take $A = I$ to get $f(X) = 0$ and think about the convexity of that function.

Comment: @RobertIsrael's point ends the discussion. The *domain of the function is not a convex set*, and that is a necessary criterion for convexity. Even $f(X)=\|X\|_F^2$, which is trivially convex, becomes non-convex when restricted to a domain like $X^TX=I$.

Answer (score 2):

(**EDIT**: If $A,X$ are both square, then ...) As the comment suggest, we know that since the determinant is multiplicative and $\det X^T=\det X$, we have that $$\det(X^TAX)=\alpha\det(X)^2$$
where $\alpha=\det(A)>0$.

However, the function $g(x)=x^2$ is *not* [logarithmically convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_convex_function), therefore the function $f(X)$ is not either.

Comment: Does anything change when you consider that $X$ and $A$ are not of the same dimension and $X$ is not square?

Comment: @user23658, that is an interesting question.

Comment: The multiplicity of the determinant only holds under square $X$ and $A$, I believe. Not sure tho! That's why I ask.

Comment: My instinct is telling me the square case suggests the general $f(X)$ is not concave, let me think on it...

Answer (score 0):

The Hessian can be used to find a sufficient (but not necessary) condition for convexity.  According to the author, the first derivative of the objective function is
$$
D^1 := \frac{\partial}{\partial X} (\log\det(X^T A X)) = 2(X^T A X)^{-1} AX = 2 B^{-1} A X
$$
The second derivative can be computed by going into index notation (summation over repeated indices).  Then
$$
  (D^1)_{in} = 2B^{-1}_{il} A_{l m} X_{mn}
$$
Then
$$
 (D^2)_{inpq} := \frac{\partial (D^1)_{in}}{\partial X_{pq}} = 2\left[\frac{\partial B^{-1}_{il}}{\partial X_{pq}} X_{mn} + B^{-1}_{il} \frac{\partial X_{mn}}{\partial X_{pq}}\right] A_{lm}
$$
Now, (without symmetrizing)
$$
  \frac{\partial X_{mn}}{\partial X_{pq}} = \delta_{mp}\delta_{nq}
$$
Therefore,
$$
  B_{il}^{-1} \frac{\partial X_{mn}}{\partial X_{pq}} A_{lm} = B_{il}^{-1} \delta_{mp}\delta_{nq}  A_{lm} = \delta_{nq} B_{il}^{-1} A_{lp}
$$
Consider the case where $A = I$. Then $B = X^T A X = X^T X = I$ and $D^1 = 2X$. So
$$
  (D^2)_{inpq} = 2\delta_{ip}\delta_{nq}\,.
$$
That is the simplest result you can get because $X$ is not square. Not sure if this helps in determining convexity.

Comment: Not sure if you saw the edit above but the derivative you use should have an inverse and be scaled by 2.